# Не могу отправить сообщение в SendBird

Tags: api

Настроил api sendbird. подключаюсь, получаю сообщение. но когда пытаюсь отправить сообщение, получаю ошибку

```
code: 900020
message: "Not a member."
name: "SendBirdException"
```

При том, что в панели говорит, что я онлайн. Кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

Просто надо было еще войти в канал - Entering an Open Channel